# Yes/No : Is $ P$ is the subspace of all real valued continuous functions on $\Bbb R$.?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the given statement is  true or false ?

Given  $f_n(x)=x^n$ for $x\in\Bbb R$ and let $ P=\operatorname{span}\{f_0,f_1,f_2,\cdots\}$ . Then

$ P$ is the subspace  space of all real valued continuous functions on $\Bbb R$.

My attempt:  I thinks  this statement is false . Take $g(x) = \sin x $

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Saying "$P$ is the subspace space" isn't grammatically correct and doesn't make sense.  It is true that $P$ is a subspace of the space of all real-valued continuous functions (but this space has lots of other subspaces too).  It is not true that $P$ equals the space of all real-valued continuous functions.  But it is unclear which of those two statements you are asking about.

Comment: @NateEldredge  that is  typo  mistake  .........But here  only subspace is there,,,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. If we're being super rigorous, you should show that the $\sin$ function is not a polynomial. To do this, you can argue that $\sin(x)=0$ for infinitely many $x$, while polynomials have finitely many roots.

Comment: Another argument is that the $n$'th derivative of a degree $n$ polynomial is $0$ but the $n$'th derivative of the sine function is not.